# Crystal Reports - Create a Parameter by Grouping a Field

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports, field, grouping

I am trying to create a parameter that allows me to select either A or B. A is a group of people from A-M, B is a group of people from N-Z. I am having trouble creating defining

```
A = (people from A-M)
B = (people from N-Z)
```

then making the parameter for the user, the results should populate "people from A-M" when the user chooses "A" and similarly for B.

Comment: Can you post an example of what you've already tried?

Comment: Hi Mike,

I tried a few things. First, the "Field" doesnt exist in the tables. I started with a binary (either Primary or Secondary) So I tried:

1) created in "Formula Fields" something called "Name"

2) defined "Name"

if {Customer.CustID} startswith "A" then
{?Name}='Primary' 
else {?Name}='Secondary'

3) tried to turn "Name" into a "Parameter" so that the user would be faced with the question "Name" and would input either "Primary" or "Secondary" .
But I have not been able to make this a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

record-selection formula:

```
...
(
  SELECT {?My Parameter}
  // A = A-M
  CASE "A":{Customer.Contact Last Name}<"N"
  // B = N-Z
  CASE "B":{Customer.Contact Last Name}>="N"
)
...
```

Comment: Hi Craig, thank you for the prompt reply. I'm working on testing this right away.

Comment: Your syntax model worked in the Formula Fields. But I am having trouble implementing it as a Parameter. How can I make this go from being a definition in Formula Fields, to a Parameter?

Comment: You can use a parameter field to allow the user to make the selection (A or B); the selected value drives the record-selection formula.  You can't covert this logic to a parameter--it doesn't work that way.